# Error en fetch al consumir un web service en una aplicación hibrida realizada con apache cordova

Tags: ajax, apache, cordova, fetch

Tengo el siguiente problema sin resolver desde hace semanas:

Tengo una pequeña aplicación híbrida para móvil realizada con apache cordova (sin uso de frameworks tipo ionic jquery mobile, etc...)

Esta aplicación realiza una llamada a un web service para recuperar un json. Para ello utilizo la función fetch de javascript

Al probar la aplicación con phonegap desde el movil funciona perfectamente

Al compilar, generar la firma y instalarla como icono de escritorio en el movil, la llamada al web service deja de funcionar (aparece un error del tipo: fail to fetch)

En el config.xml de la aplicación tengo:

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="1.0.0" />
<access origin="http://*" />
<allow-navigation href="*" />
```

En el archivo AndroidManifest.xml tengo:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

En el index.html, dentro de la meta de content-security-policy tengo

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline' http://alcyon-it.com/; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' ; media-src *; img-src 'self' data: content:">
```

En la llamada ajax al web service tengo:

```
fetch(url, {
   method: 'POST', 
   mode: 'cors', 
   body: datos,
   cache: 'no-cache'
})
```

Y en el web service php al que llamo (que es propio) tengo:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST');
```

Es decir, tengo activo todo para que la llamada funcione pero sin embargo no hay forma de que lo haga

Agracedería si hay alguien que pueda orientarme